# Login in to website with php and MySQL

Tags: php, user-accounts

On my website so far a user can add their username, password and email to a MySQL database through php. I want to now let a user type those same credentials (username and password) into forms and then run a php script and check if the Username and passwords are in the database. How would write this script?

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions related to YOUR code, not requests to code something for you.  Read around online and try to write your own code.  If you get stuck, come back, and ask a specific question here.  At that point, we'll be glad to help!

Comment: This is too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  Which part of this, specifically, are you having trouble with?

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: i hope you are not storing the password as plain text

Comment: Well I tried to make the php script connect to the database and I said that if the string that was equal to the username and if the string that was equal to the password was equal then create a session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a php function that gets what the user enters, then select them from your user table. If it returns something, say its is already in the database.

Example:

```
SELECT uname, pw FROM users WHERE uname="userNameInput" AND pw="userPwInput";
```

if this returns a row, it already is in the db.

You can then run this function on your choice of hitting a button or in every key stroke by calling the function with ajax.